# Displaying values from aggregating functions on JSP

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsp, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and JPA. I have entity class CompanyRate.

CompanyRate.java

```
@Entity
public class CompanyRate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idRate;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int atmosphere;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int salary;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int opportunityToDevelop;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int socialPackage;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Company.class)
    Company company;
}
```

I want to display AVG values of atmosphere, salary, opportunityToDevelop, socialPackage where company.idComapny = ? on JSP.

Ofc I can use getResultList() on executed query and diplay it on JSP using . But I wanna assign each result for single variable. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I can execute single query for each variable, but there is a way to do it using only one query?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT c.id,
       AVG(t.atmosphere), 
       AVG(t.salary), 
       AVG(t.opportunityToDevelop), 
       AVG(t.socialPackage)
  FROM table t, company c
 WHERE t.companyid = c.id
   AND c.id IN (:companyIds)
 GROUP BY c.id;
```

Translating the above into HQL/JPQL or leveraging Hibernate or JPA criteria APIs should be a trivial exercise.

Just be sure to call `setParameter("companyIds", listOfCompanyIds)` on the constructed `Query` and then call `getResultList()` or `list()` depending on the API you use.